# How to find new elements in json text compared to older version with Python

Tags: python, json

I am pulling json from a website everyday and need to be able to filter out all of the old entries from previous days and cut the text down to new entries. Right now I have two text files, prevJson and newJson. How can I compare these two text files and only return the json that is in newJson but not in prevJson?

Here my code so far:

```
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen
from jsondiff import diff

with open('prevJson', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read().replace('\n', '')

with open('newJson test', 'r') as file2:
    data2 = file2.read().replace('\n', '')

difference = diff(data, data2)
print(difference)
```

This is the prevJson:

```
{'date': '2021-07-18', 'time': '4:00pm', 'title': 'Venues', 'data': {'monitor': [{'Venue': '99 Bikes Bondi Junction', 'Address': '228 Oxford Street', 'Suburb': 'Bondi Junction', 'Date': 'Saturday 10 July 2021', 'Time': '12:45pm to 2:45pm', 'Alert': 'Get tested immediately and self-isolate for 14 days.', 'Lon': '151.2429926', 'Lat': '-33.89015617', 'HealthAdviceHTML': "Anyone who attended this venue is a <a href='https://www.health.nsw.gov.au/Infectious/factsheets/Pages/advice-for-contacts.aspx'>close contact</a> and must immediately <a href='https://www.nsw.gov.au/covid-19/how-to-protect-yourself-and-others/clinics'>get tested</a> and <a href='https://www.nsw.gov.au/covid-19/what-you-can-and-cant-do-under-rules/self-isolation'>self-isolate</a> for 14 days regardless of the result, and call 1800 943 553 unless they have already been contacted by NSW Health.", 'Last updated date': 'Monday 12 July 2021'}
```

This is the newJson:

```
{'date': '2021-07-18', 'time': '4:00pm', 'title': 'Venues', 'data': {'monitor': [{'Venue': '99 Bikes Bondi Junction', 'Address': '228 Oxford Street', 'Suburb': 'Bondi Junction', 'Date': 'Saturday 10 July 2021', 'Time': '12:45pm to 2:45pm', 'Alert': 'Get tested immediately and self-isolate for 14 days.', 'Lon': '151.2429926', 'Lat': '-33.89015617', 'HealthAdviceHTML': "Anyone who attended this venue is a <a href='https://www.health.nsw.gov.au/Infectious/factsheets/Pages/advice-for-contacts.aspx'>close contact</a> and must immediately <a href='https://www.nsw.gov.au/covid-19/how-to-protect-yourself-and-others/clinics'>get tested</a> and <a href='https://www.nsw.gov.au/covid-19/what-you-can-and-cant-do-under-rules/self-isolation'>self-isolate</a> for 14 days regardless of the result, and call 1800 943 553 unless they have already been contacted by NSW Health.", 'Last updated date': 'Monday 12 July 2021'} hello
```

I expected the program to return "hello" but instead it returned:

```
{'date': '2021-07-18', 'time': '4:00pm', 'title': 'Venues', 'data': {'monitor': [{'Venue': '99 Bikes Bondi Junction', 'Address': '228 Oxford Street', 'Suburb': 'Bondi Junction', 'Date': 'Saturday 10 July 2021', 'Time': '12:45pm to 2:45pm', 'Alert': 'Get tested immediately and self-isolate for 14 days.', 'Lon': '151.2429926', 'Lat': '-33.89015617', 'HealthAdviceHTML': "Anyone who attended this venue is a <a href='https://www.health.nsw.gov.au/Infectious/factsheets/Pages/advice-for-contacts.aspx'>close contact</a> and must immediately <a href='https://www.nsw.gov.au/covid-19/how-to-protect-yourself-and-others/clinics'>get tested</a> and <a href='https://www.nsw.gov.au/covid-19/what-you-can-and-cant-do-under-rules/self-isolation'>self-isolate</a> for 14 days regardless of the result, and call 1800 943 553 unless they have already been contacted by NSW Health.", 'Last updated date': 'Monday 12 July 2021'} hello
```

Comment: What's the problem with the code you have now?

Comment: I've tested it by adding 1 word to newJson and it returns a significant portion of the json with the added word at the end

Comment: Please provide example, like I have this in `prevJson` and this `newJson` and I added this and I got this, I expected to get this!

Comment: I added the received and expected response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `newJson` is not a valid JSON.

I copied/pasted both 'JSONs' and they are actually both not valid. The `prevJson` was missing closing brackets, in total `}]}}`. Same issue with the `newJson`. Also, you used `'` (single quotes) instead of `"` (double quotes). JSON requires `"` (double quotes).

The value for key `HealthAdviceHTML` included `"` (double quotes). These need to be escaped by placing a `\` in front.

Next thing is that you're not loading the JSONs as JSON, you're loading them as strings. This is why the `diff()` is returning the whole thing, as the string itself is not the same for `data1` and `data2`. This is also why it didn't throw an error for the incorrectly formatted JSONs.

Also, to add something to a JSON, you need to add key/value pairs, not just a single unquoted word. This will never work. Check how I changed the `newJson`.

All that being said, below are the 2 properly formatted JSONs. You can see Stackoverflow [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) is properly coloring the syntax. (Use ```json)

Further down is the code to properly load the JSON files, so you can compare them using the `diff()` function.

**prevJson**

```json
{
    "date": "2021-07-18",
    "time": "4:00pm",
    "title": "Venues",
    "data": {
        "monitor": [
            {
                "Venue": "99 Bikes Bondi Junction",
                "Address": "228 Oxford Street",
                "Suburb": "Bondi Junction",
                "Date": "Saturday 10 July 2021",
                "Time": "12:45pm to 2:45pm",
                "Alert": "Get tested immediately and self-isolate for 14 days.",
                "Lon": "151.2429926",
                "Lat": "-33.89015617",
                "HealthAdviceHTML": "Anyone who attended this venue is a <a href=\"https: //www.health.nsw.gov.au/Infectious/factsheets/Pages/advice-for-contacts.aspx\">close contact</a> and must immediately <a href=\"https://www.nsw.gov.au/covid-19/how-to-protect-yourself-and-others/clinics\">get tested</a> and <a href=\"https://www.nsw.gov.au/covid-19/what-you-can-and-cant-do-under-rules/self-isolation\">self-isolate</a> for 14 days regardless of the result, and call 1800 943 553 unless they have already been contacted by NSW Health.",
                "Last updated date": "Monday 12 July 2021"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**newJson**

You can see I added the key `hello` with the value `Dhar_`. JSON requires key/value pairs...

```json
{
    "date": "2021-07-18",
    "time": "4:00pm",
    "title": "Venues",
    "data": {
        "monitor": [
            {
                "Venue": "99 Bikes Bondi Junction",
                "Address": "228 Oxford Street",
                "Suburb": "Bondi Junction",
                "Date": "Saturday 10 July 2021",
                "Time": "12:45pm to 2:45pm",
                "Alert": "Get tested immediately and self-isolate for 14 days.",
                "Lon": "151.2429926",
                "Lat": "-33.89015617",
                "HealthAdviceHTML": "Anyone who attended this venue is a <a href=\"https: //www.health.nsw.gov.au/Infectious/factsheets/Pages/advice-for-contacts.aspx\">close contact</a> and must immediately <a href=\"https://www.nsw.gov.au/covid-19/how-to-protect-yourself-and-others/clinics\">get tested</a> and <a href=\"https://www.nsw.gov.au/covid-19/what-you-can-and-cant-do-under-rules/self-isolation\">self-isolate</a> for 14 days regardless of the result, and call 1800 943 553 unless they have already been contacted by NSW Health.",
                "Last updated date": "Monday 12 July 2021"
            }
        ],
        "hello": "Dhar_"
    }
}
```

**jsoncompare.py**

```py
from jsondiff import diff
import json


with open('prevJson.json') as infile:
    notajson = infile.read().replace('\n', '')
print(f'notajson type:\n{type(notajson)}\n')


with open('prevJson.json') as infile:
    data1 = json.loads(infile.read().replace('\n', ''))
with open('newJson.json') as infile:
    data2 = json.loads(infile.read().replace('\n', ''))
print(f'data1 type:\n{type(data1)}\n')


difference = diff(data1, data2)
print(difference)
```

**output**

```
notajson type:
<class 'str'>

data1 type:
<class 'dict'>

{'data': {'hello': 'Dhar_'}}
```